# How to setHeader in Camel Test

Tags: apache-camel, apache-camel-cdi

I am working with the task in which, I have set header in one of the processor.

```java
exchange.getIn().setHeader("ResourceSpec", equipmentSpec.getSpec());
```

While writing the test cases, it was expecting for value.because of that test cases getting failed.

**Mock-RouteTest:**

```java
void advice(@Observes CamelContextStartingEvent event, CamelContext context) throws Exception {

    context.getRouteDefinition(test.update)
           .adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
               @Override
               public void configure() {           
                   weaveByToString(".*lineInquiryBy.*")
                       .replace()
                       .to("mock:lineInquiry");
               }
           });
```

Need help to set header in mock. So that while executing, processor can get the value.

Using camel-test and camel-test-cdi.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question. What I understood:

1. You have a processor that sets the header `ResourceSpec`
2. You have a test that removes that processor with `adviceWith` from the route
3. Therefore a later route step fails because the header `ResourceSpec` is not set

If I understood your question correct, you can simply "insert" the `setHeader` where you remove the processor

```
weaveByToString(".*lineInquiryBy.*")
    .replace()
    .to("mock:lineInquiry")
    .setHeader("ResourceSpec", constant("static value"));
```

If you need a dynamic value (for example from a message header), you can use the [Camel Simple](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/languages/simple-language.html) expression language:

```
.setHeader("ResourceSpec", simple("${header.myHeader}"));
```

Comment: i tried it in same way...but it was throwing error.

Comment: 1) setHeader(String name),  2) setHeader(String name, Expression expression),   3) setHeader(String name, Supplier<Object> Supplier)...there are the options i can see it in suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I updated my answer with two examples for an expression. one with a static value, applied with `constant`. And one with a dynamic value taken from a message header, applied with `simple`.

Comment: @burki..Thanks..i was getting exception on a line before getHeader()